# newInstance() | ClassNotFoundException | NoClassDefFounfError

Tags: java

following is the code, when i am giving command java Test A then i am getting error NoClassDefFoundError and when i give command java Test S then error is ClassNotFound.

As per my knowledge if newInstance() is used and class is not found then ClassNotFound error should com

Why is there difference in the errors?

[image]

```
class Test {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
{
    System.out.println("In Main Method");
    Object o = Class.forName(args[0]).newInstance();
    System.out.println(o.getClass().getName());
}

}

class Student
{

}

class Teacher
{

}
```

Comment: What is it you think the "A" is doing in your command...

Comment: @slambeth A or Student or S is the class name for which object has to be created

Comment: ...yes, but you'll need that class to actually exist in your classpath to load it and create an instance of it.  As an experiment, try your command with "java.lang.String" in place of the "A".

Comment: @slambeth correct and if class is not found then classnotfoundexception will be thrown.

My question is in case I am passing A as class then I am getting noclassdeffounderror - why is it so?

Comment: Not sure what you did, but ClassNotFoundException is all that is going to happen with Class.forName();

Answer (score -1):

As per my knowledge if newInstance() is used and class is not found then ClassNotFound error should com

```
    @CallerSensitive
public static Class<?> forName(String className)
            throws ClassNotFoundException {
    Class<?> caller = Reflection.getCallerClass();
    return forName0(className, true, ClassLoader.getClassLoader(caller), caller);
}
```

`forName` method is throwing the `ClassNotFoundException` exception.

`newInstance` method is throwing `InstantiationException` and `IllegalAccessException`

I'm not able to reproduce your issue, in each case I get a `ClassNotFoundException`